# Changing Questions to not be open ended

Tags: discussion

I'd like to think that SO can be a place for newer members to ask questions they are very stumped with.  I agree that a user shouldn't just post, "Hey, I want to do X, can you help?".  But in some cases, a user provides a little bit of detail and with a lot of massaging the question could be useful to other members.  I find these posts a lot for someone learning/starting to learn a new technology or language.

Are posts like this worth trying to salvage with extensive editing to make them phrased in a way people don't instantly downvote?  I find people who phrase a question in a way that makes them seem new to SO instantly gets it downvoted.  To what degree should I concern myself with trying to "save" these posts for the good of the community, or should I let them just burn and get closed?

Comment: Only you can answer the degree of concern issue... It is a subjective thing.

Comment: If you can edit questions to not be open-ended, please do go ahead! If they were closed, vote to reopen. You'll do the OP a service teaching them, certainly. However, you'll find that there is a lot of work to be done.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I also assume most of the OP are just looking for a quick answer and are too lazy to research, but there are newbie questions from newbie posters that I feel are very hard to find in the sometimes constant posts of, "I want you to do X for me... GO!"  So that fixing it to teach them, I assume is falling on deaf ears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I often edit questions that have particular value to the site. If it is one of a number of like questions I flag it and move on. If it is special and it enriches SO, then I edit it. No point in wasting your time on  something useless, there are enough questions of value in need of your time.

Comment: it's tough finding those ones needing my time.  Sometimes, it's nice to get a softball question to get your mind stretched out for a day of developing.  Nice warm ups for the "big" issues.  It's good to know I am not the only one trying to save some of these "lesser" posts.

Comment: You are not alone.